# How do i restrict one digit per circular textbox in Angular?

Tags: angular

I just wanted to restrict one digit per circular textbox. I don't know quite how to achieve it.
Here is my template code:

```html
<input type="text" id="code1" formControlName="otpcode" class="form-control" style="height:50px; width:50px;border-radius:100%;font-size: 20px;" name="otpcode" placeholder="{{'features.otp.password' | translate}}" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.otpcode.errors }"
/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="code2" formControlName="otpcode" class="form-control" style="height:50px; width:50px;border-radius:100%;" name="otpcode" placeholder="{{'features.otp.password' | translate}}" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.otpcode.errors }"
/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="code3" formControlName="otpcode" class="form-control" style="height:50px; width:50px;border-radius:100%;" name="otpcode" placeholder="{{'features.otp.password' | translate}}" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.otpcode.errors }"
/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="code4" formControlName="otpcode" class="form-control" style="height:50px; width:50px;border-radius:100%;" name="otpcode" placeholder="{{'features.otp.password' | translate}}" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.otpcode.errors }"
/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

If there is another way to refine this code using ngModel please let me know that too.

Thanks

Comment: Try this `<input type="text" max="1" id="code1" formControlName="otpcode" class="form-control" style="height:50px; width:50px;border-radius:100%;font-size: 20px;" name="otpcode" placeholder="{{'features.otp.password' | translate}}" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.otpcode.errors }"
/>`

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, i should have just used maxlength attribute and to put an auto tab a onInputEntry() to handle the requirement for moving cursor to next text box.

```
<input type="text" id="code1" formControlName="otpcode1"
                                    class="form-control circle circle-with-text mr-2" name="otpcode"
                                    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.otpcode.errors }" maxlength="1"
                                    (input)="onInputEntry($event, code2)" />
```